# smarty php variable not appearing

Tags: php, smarty

I am using the smarty templating system for php. I have the following within a .tpl file:

```
 <a href=\"{/literal}/view/{$tablename}/
```

where $tablename is a php variable defined in the php file that calls the .tpl

```
$tablename = 'string';
```

However running the script only

```
href="/view//"
```

is visible. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

This

```
$tablename = 'string';
```

is not enough to populate a variable into Smarty.

You need to use

```
$Smarty->assign("tablename", $tablename);
```

`$Smarty` being your initialized Smarty object, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Are you assigning to variable to the smarty instance? e.g with [assign()](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/api.assign.php)?

```
 $smarty->assign('tablename', $tablename);
```

See also the [manual page on assigning variables from PHP](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.variables.php#language.assigned.variables)